# how to make vim recognize CJK characters and render them larger than ASCII?

Tags: vim, font-size, cjk

I am using vim to work on both Chinese and Western text. The default font size is okay for Western text, but the Chinese characters, while readable, are too small
for my taste. 
Can I tell vim to render CJK fonts with, say, 14pt while not affecting the font size of all other text?

Thanks for your ideas/solutions!

Guba

Comment: I think that would depend more on your terminal (emulator) than on the program running inside.

Comment: Unless OP means GVim, which doesn't run in a terminal... in which case the question should be clarified.  Not that it helps: GVim requires that all fonts are of the same size.

Comment: Hello, sorry for being unclear. Yes, I am talking about GVim (under Ubuntu Jaunty). So, is there no way to tell GVim "if the font is CJK, render in 14pt, else render in 12pt"? Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using gVim try to `set guifontwide` to different font. You can try MS Mincho or MS Gothic on Windows.

Note, that on all GUI versions but GTK+ 2 `guifontwide` option is used only when `encoding` is set to `utf-8` and `guifontset` is empty or invalid. More info in `:help guifontwide`.

Comment: With the comment and keywords here given, I was able to get ahead. See http://www.nabble.com/To-many-inter-character-space-when-display-Simplified-Chinese-(zh_CN)-td20784795.html
Thanks!